# Использование vue-i18n внутри script

Tags: vue.js

Есть небольшой проект [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/i18n-7luth?fontsize=14)

Использую [vue-i18n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-i18n) переводчик.

**Hello World template:**

```
<h1>{{msg}}</h1>
```

**И script:**

```
data() {
    return {
      msg: `{{ $t("welcomeMsg") }}`
    }
  }
```

**Plugins/i18n.js :**

```
const messages = {
  en: {
    welcomeMsg: "Welcome to Your Vue.js App",
  },
  es: {
    welcomeMsg: "Bienvenido a tu aplicación Vue.js",
  }
};
```

**Вопрос:** Как я могу использовать vue-i18n внутри script подобно этого `msg:{{ $t("welcomeMsg") }}`?

**P.S:** `this.$t("welcomeMsg")` это работает, но не переводит!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По аналогии с [Использование локализованных строк в заголовках страницы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1056300/213987)

```
return {
  msg: this.$i18n.t("welcomeMsg")
}
```

Проверил — работает.