# Использование локализованных строк в заголовках страницы

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Я использую vue-i18n для перевода приложения на другие языки:

```
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <h2>{{ $t('pageName.title') }}</h2>
        </div>
```

И всё было неплохо, пока я не захотел использовать $t за пределами шаблонов вью, например в заголовках страницы

Было:

```
export default {
  name: "CurrenciesList",
  metaInfo: {
    title: "Currencies"
  },
```

Недолго думая я написал:

```
export default {
  name: "CurrenciesList",
  metaInfo: {
    title: this.$i18n.t("currency.list.title")
  },
```

И оно не заработало:

```
  TypeError: undefined has no properties
```

При этом плагин точно подключен, вот main.js:

```
import VueI18n from "vue-i18n";
import { languages, defaultLocale } from "./i18n/index";

...

Vue.use(VueI18n);
const messages = Object.assign(languages);
const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: defaultLocale,
  fallbackLocale: "en",
  messages
});

...

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  i18n,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Comment: Видимо то что и мне нужно ) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1039236/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-vue-i18n-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-script

только у меня не правильно сформулировано

Comment: @HamSter Да, это подходит и вам - я только что проверил что `this.$i18n.t("string")` сработает внутри `data()`

Comment: @AK, спасибо!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Долго разбирался в теме [Use $t function outside template](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/17), в итоге [нашёл подходящее решение в комментариях](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/149#issuecomment-348692403):

> Instead of defining metaInfo as an object, define it as a function

Страница:

```
export default {
  name: "CurrenciesList",
  metaInfo() {
    return {
      title: this.$i18n.t("currency.list.title"),
    }
  },
```

И в App.vue:

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  metaInfo: {
    title: "default title",
    titleTemplate: "%s | PROJECT_TITLE"
  }
};
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: А если есть такой метод:

 `removeItem: async function (position) {
        let self = this;
        const h = this.$createElement;
        const messageVNode = h('div', {class: ['modal-complete']}, [
          h('div', {
            domProps: {
              innerHTML: "<span class="popup-meta">Are you sure you want to remove this item? </span>"
            }
          })
        ]);
        this.$bvModal.msgBoxConfirm([messageVNode], { ... `

Comment: Как тогда перевести "Are you sure you want to remove this item?"